# Spring security login point to MySQL database and other functionality should use SQL Server database

Tags: mysql, spring, security, authentication

In my project I want to make spring security login functionality to point to MySQL database and other functionality of my project is running in SQL server how can I make spring security login functionality to point to MySQL database.

I created to data source namely :
dataSource and dataSourceMySQL

dataSource is pointing to SQL Server database and dataSourceMySQL is pointing to MySQL database. But I don't know how to go further. How can I achieve "to make spring security login functionality to point to MySQL database"?

Comment: One does not depend on the other. You setup Spring Security using one datasource, then use the other datasource for your app.  Here is a posting that speaks to the former (might be slightly dated): http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/

Answer (score 0):

in your spring security context you can use

> authentication-manager

with

> authentication-provider

then with

> jdbc-user-service

and set

> data-source-ref

with you mysql datasource as in below:

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />
        <security:jdbc-user-service id="jdbcUserService"
            data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```